# Taglib <c:out> to be act as a link to go to new page

Tags: jsp, jstl

i am selecting some content from database and displaying it.i m trying t create a link to that output so that on clicking it it will go to another page.

```
 <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
      SELECT * from questions;
 </sql:query>
```

```
   <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">

       <tr> 
           <td style="font-size: 18px;color: royalblue"> <a href="nextpage.jsp"><c:out       value="${row.ques}"/></a> 
           </td>
       </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: What's the specific issue? If you want to use a GET param, e.g., in the URL, put the `<c:out>` with something like an ID in the `href` attribute. Also, consider just using JSP EL instead of `<c:out>`. And consider not using the `sql` tags?!

Comment: how to use EL for accessing database

Comment: It won't be. DB access happens on the Java side, in a servlet or other framework artifact.

Comment: ya,i tried in servlet but i m unable to save the the output of an sql in the String array.It gives the error of Object cannot be converted to String

Comment: Because it can't. Data should be transferred to JSP pages in a DTO.